# Cocoon: allow users only to add not edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have a Ticket model, which has many Comments. In the edit view, I allow users to add comments, using cocoon.  However I want to ensure that previous comments can't be edited.  In the view I use a partial called indexlist to render all the previous comments (and delete them).  For brevity, I haven't included that code.  So in the view I have

```
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    <%= render 'comments/indexlist' %>

    <br /><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :comments do |tc| %>
      <%= render partial: 'comment_fields', locals: {f: tc} %>
    <% end %>

    <div>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Comment', f, :comments, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
```

The problem is using f.fields_for :comments do |tc| ... is that it renders each previous comment, but without it, if there are validation errors on the subform all the data is lost during the form round trip.
I'm sure there's an easy solution to this one...

Comment: So the user can't edit the ticket either?

Comment: Users can edit tickets, but not edit comments.  So you can't change what somebody else said is the idea.  In fact what I want is identical to the comment function here: a list of previous comments, which you can delete (or in fact edit) if you have the permissions; an add comment button; and on validation failure of the comment, the comment to persist through the form round trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll need to have a conditional in the comment_fields

```
<% if f.object.user_id == current_user.id %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <%= f.object.content %>
<% end %>
```

That will let you edit your own comments.

The other way you could do it is have one form purely for the ticket and use ajax to add/edit comments rather than use cocoon and nested_attributes which would be the like the way stackoverflow works.

Comment: Ah-ha. f.object is just what I need.  Then I can run that through any conditions, or use Pundit or what have you. Perfect.  My only remaining question is then how I write a condition to include only the new comment, currently being written but failing the validation, because f.object.id.nil? seems to be causing problems: it always makes a new partial appear!

Comment: Ignore previous comment, using f.object.created_at.nil? sorts it out!

Comment: @thenapking `f.object.new_record?` might be better